# Will my webpart still work?

Tags: visual-studio

If I create a web part using a Visual Studio trial version, and the trial expires, will my web part continue working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes it will. If you have compiled it and packaged it (in a .wsp or .app depending on the technology you use to develop) it will not have any relations to a specific Visual Studio instance